# I just can't seem to find a solution for this error

Tags: java, eclipse

Getting `ClassNotFoundException` in the following code, if someone had something similar please help.

```
package paket;

public class Klasa1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("JEBI ME");

    }
}
```

**That's the error I get:**

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: Post all code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: i don't think code is the problem. Something else must be but i can't figure out what exacly

Comment: code works, is the jdk configured correctly or did you recently started using eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I just started using eclipse. Can you tell me what do you mean by jdk being correctly configured?

Comment: I can only run java through CMD. In eclipse i always get the same error.

Comment: Is _Project > Build Automatically_ checked? Is this Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10)?

Comment: Yea build automatically is checked and version is 2018-12 (4.10).

Comment: i am not too sure about the java jdk 11, but  if you want the code to just run try switching to java se 1.8 through right click `jre system library in the package explorer > properties > select JavaSe 1.8 from dropdown` (if u have it configured)

Comment: It doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Have you already tried to ***clean*** your project?

Comment: thank you for everyone taking the time to help me. The problem was because workspace for eclipse was in C:\Users\Đurađ\workspace, it seems that java couldn't find it or something(because there was đ in the name of the folder) so i changed the workspace in another folder.